# Rust borrow checker prevents reuse after end of scope

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Here's some code that I'm having trouble getting to compile:

```
struct HasVec {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}

fn get_or_make<'a>(container: &'a mut HasVec) -> &'a mut u8 {
    let ref mut vec = container.vec;
    {
        for element in vec.iter_mut() {
            if *element > 9 {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
    vec.push(10);
    vec.last_mut().unwrap()
}
```

The output from the compiler is:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
   |
8  |             for element in vec.iter_mut() {
   |                            --- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
14 |         vec.push(10);
   |         ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
15 |         vec.last_mut().unwrap()
16 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here


error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
   |
8  |             for element in vec.iter_mut() {
   |                            --- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |         vec.last_mut().unwrap()
   |         ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
16 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*vec` as mutable more than once at a time
   |
8  |             for element in vec.iter_mut() {
   |                            --- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
15 |         vec.last_mut().unwrap()
   |         ^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
16 |     }
   |     - first borrow ends here
```

Isn't the borrow supposed to end at the end of the scope on line 13? I haven't found any way to refactor that code that will satisfy the borrow checker. Putting `let ref mut vec = container.vec;` inside of the code block with the for loop and another right after that block doesn't work and neither does accessing `container.vec` directly without a ref variable.

I'm using Rust 1.16.0.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with `return` not correctly ending the scope.

Comment: FYI, it's more idiomatic to do `let vec = &mut container.vec;` and `for element in &mut vec`.

Comment: As a workaround, [you can use the index of the item in the array instead](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=9406b51a0503c37e2de9a5a4b048d117&version=stable).